# Pass JavaScript variable through URL

Tags: javascript

I have a page that sets a few variables using javascript `Math.random()` as shown.

```
var RandomValue1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var RandomValue2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
var string = array1[RandomValue1];
var string = array2[RandomValue2];
```

I would like to allow a user to pass the `RandomValue` value through the `URL` to another person. When the second person goes to the shared `URL`, `RandomValue` is the value as the first person - so that the second person sees the same 'string' as the first person.

I am fairly new to web design and web programming so I don't know if this needs to be handled on the server-side or client-side.

I assume I need to pass a url something like `page1.html?RandomValue1=1&RandomValue2=3` but I cannot get the page to then set those variables and load.  Can this be done in `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read GET variables with javascript. Here is an example function ([source](http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/)):

```
function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
}
```

Usage:

```
var first = getUrlVars()["id"];
var second = getUrlVars()["page"];

alert(first);
alert(second);
```

Comment: I just implemented this method and it worked like a charm!  Thank you!  I will have to investigate more what the var part is doing - .replace(???)function.. - I don't quite understand, but I was able to pull the data I needed from the URL.  Again many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct. You need to put those variables into the URL as PARAMETERS. I would further suggest using a "#" instead of actual parameters so you don't risk updating the page each time, so the URL would look like mydomain.com/page.html#RandomValue1=1&RandomValue2=3.

You can use Javascript to get / set those parameters by the window.location.href method. On page load, the Javascript will check to see whether there is a "#" and parse anything after it in the URL. After the page has loaded, a Javascript can be used to update those parameters.

See the following link for full documentation on how to use window.location:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Oh, and here's a javascript library that might help get you there faster. It works with the hash ('#') and will automatically parse (deparameterize) the parameters for you, assigning them to strings / objects etc. which you can then use.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in PHP.

You can put a hidden field on your page (in a form). Set the form method to GET and have the action set to another PHP page.

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="my_page.php" method="GET">
  <input id="myId" name="myName" type="hidden />
</form>
```

In the PHP page you can manage the variables with the $_GET object.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['myName'])){
    //do something with value;
  }
?>
```

Just remember that the GET and POST variables are based off the name attribute from the HTML elements. In my example, the hidden field has the name `myName`, so when I want to refer to it I use `$_GET['myName'];`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the server to coordinate the data between both clients. In other words, the first user would need to submit their random value to the server - this could be done using a GET URL like `page1.html?RandomValue1=1` although you might want to research POST requests.

Anyway, the second user could then go to the shared URL to see the value stored on the server.